Google Maps for Flutter not displaying Points of Interest
I'm using google_maps_flutter: ^2.7.0 to display a marker based on the user's location which works well, but I'm not seeing any POIs around the user. I know that they should be displayed. I am moving the Flutter app from a progressive web app to an Android & iOS apps and on the web I was seeing all POIs and was able to click on them. I would like this functionality if possible. To click on a POI and show a bottom modal with some data.
The Google Maps Android API Key is added to AndroidManifest
  <application android:label="[name]" android:name="${applicationName}" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="[apiKeyValue]"/>

The API key doesn't have any restrictions since we're only testing for now.
Testin on a real device.
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class GoogleMapWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double lat;
  final double lng;
  final String name;
  final String id;
  final dynamic height;
  final bool allRound;
  const GoogleMapWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.lat,
    required this.lng,
    required this.name,
    required this.id,
    required this.height,
    required this.allRound,
  });
  @override
  State<GoogleMapWidget> createState() => _GoogleMapWidgetState();
}

class _GoogleMapWidgetState extends State<GoogleMapWidget> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> mapController = Completer();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    mapController.future.then((controller) {
      controller.dispose();
    });
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Marker> markers = <Marker>[
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(widget.id),
        position: LatLng(widget.lat, widget.lng),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: widget.name),
      )
    ];

    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: widget.allRound
            ? BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
            : const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10.0)),
        color: Colors.grey[200],
      ),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: widget.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: GoogleMap(
          onTap: (LatLng position) {
            print(position);
          },
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(widget.lat, widget.lng),
            zoom: 17.0,
          ),
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers),
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            mapController.complete(controller);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Edit ******
Seeing these messages in the terminal
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend(18473): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend(18473): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
I/com.gps.tok(18473): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 280834(9593KB) AllocSpace objects, 67(4928KB) LOS objects, 25% free, 31MB/41MB, paused 163us,143us total 106.900ms
E/FrameEvents(18473): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(18473): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(18473): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(18473): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(18473): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(18473): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(18473): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(18473): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(18473): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(18473): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(18473): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend(18473): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.
W/ProxyAndroidLoggerBackend(18473): Too many Flogger logs received before configuration. Dropping old logs.


To display Points of Interest (POI), add the following to your style:
GoogleMap(
    style: '''[{
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [{"visibility": "on"}]
    }]''',
)

Regarding the issue with handling POI clicks, it has been reported here. If you scroll down a bit, you will find some repositories that have implemented this functionality. You can use one of those until the issue is resolved.

Thank you for your reply but it doesn't work. Still seeing map with just user location marker. Edited my question with some additional logs that I'm seeing in terminal.

@AlienDecoy weird I have tested it and it worked with your code, I tested with version google_maps_flutter: ^2.9.0 maybe that's why
